# I dont know How to solve this using php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `phpstorm` to create project using `php`, `bootstrap` and `jquery`. In this Project,I got two errors. But i don't know how to solve this error.

Can anyone tell me what is the fault? I have attached two images.

[image]

[image]

Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>boutique</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-----NavBar----->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixedtop">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">boutique</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Men<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!---Header------>
<div id="headerwrapper">
    <div id="back-flower"></div>
    <div id="logotext"></div>
    <div id="for-flower"></div>
</div>


<script>
    jquery(window).scroll(function () {
var vscroll=jquery(this).scrollTop();
jquery('#logotext').css({
    "transform" :"translate(0px,"+vscroll/2+"px)"

});
        var vscroll=jquery(this).scrollTop();
        jquery('#back-flower').css({
            "transform" :"translate("+vscroll/5+"px,-"+vscroll/12+"px)"
        });
        var vscroll=jquery(this).scrollTop();
        jquery('#fore-flower').css({
            "transform" :"translate(0px,"+vscroll/2+"px)"
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post image code in your question as it is difficult to debug into it

Comment: I have already attached it...

Comment: As text, I means to say, not in image

Comment: And please change your question title to something that describes your issue; be more specific

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dsB7mhR4

Comment: hello vendetta did u see?

Comment: `var` defines variables in the global scope. So you are trying to create `vscroll` twice. It dont like that!!!!

Comment: @php16 : Its OK, its just editor warning, ignore that, and move on with your code. And yes, for the same, remove https: from that url. Don't be too much serious about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you using same name for var? 
You can extract the scroll position using jQuery's .scrollTop() method

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Do something
});
```

Or try this;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > some_number) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem in second image?

Comment: Try to change it to: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">`
Or download it and put in folder and then use `<script src="/folder/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If you add the information _var defines variables in the global scope_ to your answer it will improve it 10 fold as it will give a reason why OP should make a change like you are suggesting

Comment: hello ivan, how to download it?where  can i put it?

Comment: @php16 Go to: https://jquery.com/download/  
Click on last link version. Last version is 3.1.1.
When you download put it in some map and then include it with <script scr="/folder(name of your folder you made)/jquery.min.js">